# Gizmos.DrawMesh does not render anything

Tags: unity, mesh

I would like to draw a procedural mesh as a gizmo:

```
Gizmos.DrawMesh(mesh);
```

however this does not render anything no matter what. I can confirm that the mesh in question is a correct one by both `GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh` assigning it to Renderer and rendering it using default material and `Gizmo.DrawLine` drawing it edge-by-edge.
No error are logged in debug window, setting position or flipping triangle orientation has no effect neither. Version of Unity is 5.6.2f1. Am I missing something?

```
void Start ()
{
   GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh; //renders without any problems
}

void OnDrawGizmos()
{
   Gizmos.color = Color.red;
   Gizmos.DrawMesh(mesh);//nothing rendered
   //renders without any problems
   for (int i = 0; i < mesh.triangles.Length / 3; i++)
   {
      Gizmos.DrawLine(mesh.vertices[mesh.triangles[i * 3 + 2]], mesh.vertices[mesh.triangles[i * 3]]);
      Gizmos.DrawLine(mesh.vertices[mesh.triangles[i * 3]], mesh.vertices[mesh.triangles[i * 3 + 1]]);
      Gizmos.DrawLine(mesh.vertices[mesh.triangles[i * 3 + 1]], mesh.vertices[mesh.triangles[i * 3 + 2]]);
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this issue with meshes I've tried so far - they all render correctly with gizmos as expected. Can you try it with variants on the problem mesh to see if there's a particular quirk to the mesh you're using that the gizmo renderer rejects?

Comment: @DMGregory It appears to be broken for every mesh not just particular one, e.g. even for trivial meshes like [5.0,4.0];[-5.0,4.0];[-5.0,-4.0];5.0,-4.0] with indices 3,2,1,1,0,3. Also forgot to mention - it is 2D (ortho camera) if that ever plays role.

Comment: It's working with every mesh I've tried, including built-in primitives and triangle meshes generated at runtime. Is it possible your winding order is causing it to be rejected as a back-face, or that it's getting drawn off-screen / too close for the near plane? Otherwise this might be a Unity bug or a corruption of some kind. See if you can DrawMesh with a primitive cube in a new project to test whether there's something amiss with your editor installation.

Comment: @DMGregory it was the normals - not that I did not try adding them but flipping orientation was also required. Never tried combination of _both_. The fact that the default amterial does not require normal did not contribute to finding the problem neither. This might be a silly error, but still I feel at least some warning like "error: unassigned normals" should be produced for a mesh being rendered, making the API more user friendly.

Answer (score 2):

Unity does not recalculate normals automatically, which in combination with the default material not requiring normals to render caused the confusion. Either

```
mesh.normals = Enumerable.Repeat(Vector3.forward, mesh.vertices.Length).ToArray();
```

or

```
mesh.RecalculateNormals();
```

will do the trick.